# Is there a way to force boto3 to use chunked upload instead of multipart upload?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

From what I understand `boto3.Client.upload_file()` will automatically use multipart uploads for dealing with larger files, and the threshold for that can be set with the `TransferConfig`.

However I want to test an S3-like API's ability to handle a chunked upload, and [calculating the signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html) for such uploads. I can't seem to find any documentation on this. Is it possible to do chunked uploads with boto3?

Comment: [Allegedly](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html), the upload_file method handles large files by chunking them.

Comment: It's not supported.  There is a long standing open [issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/751) to add such a feature.

Comment: @jarmod The wording is unfortunate but the "chunks" they refer to [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html) is multipart upload.